# How to hide the description of GRUB Menu?

Tags: grub2

As following picture,
is it possible to hide this description(in red bounding box) from Grub Menu?

[image]

Comment: You'll probably need to patch GRUB for that.

Comment: @Artem S. Tashkinov 
Thank you for your response.
Where could I find the patch or which keyword I should search for?

Comment: You'll probably need to write the patch yourself. A basic knowledge of the C language is required.  Download the source code of your distro GRUB package, unpack it and look for this message.